# recover data from zfs pool on napp-it openIndiana

Tags: zfs, data-recovery, openindiana

I just inherited a desktop PC with napp-it free (openIndiana), it was set up to work as a sort of NAS, it had two disks on 2TB and one 3TB without any redundancy, one of the drives failed and the pool is now offline.

I'm pretty new to ZFS and tried searching but so far I just found articles that I should recover from a backup, which I do not have.

The other drive contains some critical data and I'm not really comfortable experimenting on it, my question is it possible to recover anything of the pool and how would I go about doing this?

zpool status output:

```
state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices could not be opened.  There are insufficient
        replicas for the pool to continue functioning.
action: Attach the missing device and online it using 'zpool online'.
   see: http://illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-3C
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        store       UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
          c4t1d0    UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
          c4t2d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `zpool status`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a pool built from two disks as a raid-0, your data was striped over both disks. You cannot recover any data from a raid-0 when one disk is missing.

Yout only option is a professional data rescue service that can repair the faulted disk.

Comment: This is a zfs pool it's not raid if that's what you mean?, I did not set it up I just inherited it.

Comment: Based on your zpool status output, this is the correct answer. Your data is striped over two disks, similar to RAID0.